# How to setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false) to avoid truncated by '.' (dot) with specify urls in Spring?

Tags: spring, http, url

Now I have an API url like "https://domain/abc.def".

In Spring project this API is set like

```
@RequestMapping(value = {domain/{encryption}}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String method(@PathVariable("encryption") String encryption) {
        get encryption...
        do something...
}
```

When I get this "encryption" from it I only get 'abc' but not 'abc.def'.

Here is the Spring doc about it: [Spring Doc][1]

I need to setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false) to avoid URL is truncated by '.' so I created a configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
public class PathMatchConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected PathMatchConfigurer getPathMatchConfigurer() {
        PathMatchConfigurer pathMatchConfigurer = super.getPathMatchConfigurer();
        pathMatchConfigurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);

        return pathMatchConfigurer;
    }
}
```

**It does work but I do not want this feature effects on all URLs in project, so how to let it effects on specify URLs ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I take this suggest in Spring Doc

> Blockquote nother way to avoid this issue is by adding a slash at the end of our @PathVariable. This will enclose our second variable protecting it from Spring's default behavior: `@GetMapping("/example/{firstValue}/{secondValue}/")`